# visual studio 2017 remote debugging cannot link linux lib

Tags: remote-debugging, visual-studio-2017, gdbserver

I connect a linux server using ssh(vs2017), and want to debug codes though the gdb server(has been installed).But I find there are some problems in linking process. The output shows that "Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'. Cannot find or open the symbol file". Then I change the debug mode from gdbserver to gbg, but it goes into a infinite looping of "initializing Debugger".Can someone tell me what can I do? Thx

Comment: no one has met this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I thought these output errors were initially a problem. But that is not the case. You need to go to **Debug->Linux Console** to activate the Linux Console Window. You will then see the output of your application succeeded just fine. It helps to also place a breakpoint so the the gdbserver shows its working.

Comment: Great！It seems work as follow you said. Thanks very much!